# Google Drive SDK OAuth2 with multiple user account

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-oauth

If a user has several accounts in their Google, the user has to choose an account as it doesn't remember which account the user chose previously.
[image]
I have managed to make an OAuth2 authentication using these codes and the configurations guided from https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication#specifying-your-client-id-and-scopes

```
this.authenticate = function(){
    gapi.load('client:auth2',authorize);
}
function authorize(){
    gapi.client.setApiKey(API_KEY);
    gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        scope: SCOPES
    }).then(function(authResult){
        var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        auth2.signIn().then(afterSignIn);
    });
}
function afterSignIn(){
    console.log('authenticated successfully');
    $rootScope.authenticated = true;
    gapi.client.load('drive', 'v3',function(){
        $rootScope.$broadcast('authenticated');
    });
}
```

I have tried these [options](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#googleauthsigninoptions) of `GoogleAuth.signIn()`:

```
auth2.signIn({
            'prompt': '**promtOption**'
  })...
```

`none` : it doesn't authenticate

`login`: does the same as `select_account`

`consent`: does the same as `select_account`, it additionally asks for offline use permission...

`select_account`: same problem as signing in without `options`

How can I make the program remember the user selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `auth2.signIn()` will always prompt the user to sign in, even if they are already signed in. Before doing that, check to see if they are already signed in using `auth2.currentUser.get().isSignedIn()`. Here's a modified version of your code:

```
function authorize(){
    gapi.client.setApiKey(API_KEY);
    gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        scope: SCOPES
    }).then(function(authResult){
        var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        var user = auth2.currentUser.get();
        if (user.isSignedIn()) {
          afterSignIn();
        } else {
          auth2.signIn().then(afterSignIn);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer. I didn't know that OAuth2.0 handles everything for you!!!!